# Python Function: cmd subprocess

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am working on using this function someone wrote to copy files from a source to destination directory.
If I simply use the code as it is, it works, but if I call the function it wants me to pass an argument to cmd, but I am not able to figure out what argument it is looking for. Any help would be awesome!

Error:
TypeError: copyWithSubprocess() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cmd'

```
#Create a function that can be used in Windows or Linux to copy files
def copyWithSubprocess(cmd):        
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    cmd=None
    if sys.platform.startswith("win"): cmd=[print("robocopy", source_directory, destination_directory)]
    elif sys.platform.startswith("darwin"): cmd=['cp', "source", "dest"]

    if cmd: copyWithSubprocess(cmd)


#Call copyWithSubprocess function to copy directories
copyWithSubprocess()
```

Comment: copyWithSubprocess() needs something passed into it, currently you don't pass anything in and it does not have default values to fall back to

Comment: There are several things wrong with your sample code.  To begin with the tabulation is incorrect, you have some program lines in the function block that don't belong in there.  Also the original program looks odd the way it builds the command line for the darwin case.

Comment: The Windows version is not safe, and the MacOS version is needlessly inefficient (starting a separate `cp` executable has overhead one doesn't eat using Python's native file copy operations). I wouldn't advise using this code at all.

Comment: And there's a lot of general WTF here. The code after `cmd =` doesn't require a `cmd` argument to be passed to your code at all. Arguably, the first `proc =` should be moved to the very end of the function, and the recursive call should just be eliminated.

Comment: Got it. I do not end up needing to make the copy of files a function for my script but was doing so to practice and it makes sense why I had so much trouble wrapping my head around this. Thanks everyone : )